# Como ler um charde um arquivo e converter para inteiro

Tags: c

O trecho de código a seguir deveria mostrar o valor inteiro do único caractere armazenado no arquivo. quando eu coloco uma letra como 'a' por exemplo funciona. mas quando eu coloco esse simbolo: þ. e vários outros ele mostra -2 na tela. sendo que esse simbolo de acordo com a tabela ASCII tem valor 231. o codigo é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *ptr;
    char c;
    ptr = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    fscanf(ptr, "%c", &c);
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

a unica coisa armazenada em teste.txt é o simbolo þ.

Comment: O simbolo  **þ** parece não ter na tabela ASCII, fiz a leitura aqui com seu código e o valor que retornou foi -61. Qual SO vc esta usando?

Comment: Não, a tabela ASCII só vai até o código 127. Você está pegando uma extensão dela. Aí pode variar o que retorna. O caractere que você está usando provavelmente é considerado um caractere *multibyte*, por isso está gerando esta confusão. Se você abrir o arquivo em algum software que permita ler o arquivo byte a byte, provavelmente vai achar 2 ou mais. Aí o arquivo está lendo só o primeiro.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver isso. Meu SO é o Windows 7 profissional

Comment: Aconselho a leitura de [O Mínimo Absoluto Que Todo Desenvolvedor De Software Absolutamente, Positivamente Precisa Saber Sobre Unicode E Conjuntos de Caracteres (Sem Desculpas!)](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!))

Comment: De uma olhada nesta tabela http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf aqui vc pode ver o caracter que vc quer, porem ele e um pouco diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Na instrução

```
printf("%d", c);
```

o `char` é automaticamente convertido para `int` sem ser preciso fazer nada.

É parte da regra "integer promotions" (ver [6.5.2.2p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) no Standard C11 (inglês))

Comment: Por default os compiladores usam o C89. Eu próprio nunca usei o C11 mas do que parece as críticas são horríveis.

Comment: A regra é a mesma para C89 e [C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.2p6), mas eu não tenho um link para o primeiro. Quanto às críticas ... a remoção de `gets()` foi positivo! Tirando isso (eu já não usava o `gets()` anteriormente) também não uso as novidades do C11 e uso poucas do C99.

Comment: A unica razão que utilizo o C99 é para declarar variaveis em laços loop de resto não faço a mínima o que mudou.